# Mercurial API for C#

Tags: c#, api, mercurial

I'm looking for a Mercurial C# API. The only one i can find goes to a 403 page on google (http://code.google.com/p/mercurialdotnet/).

Does anyone know of one that I can use?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The link on the comment's dup was broken. I put this there and here.
http://www.ohloh.net/p/mercurialdotnet

Answer (score 13):

The Mercurial .net project referenced (mercurialdotnet) does not seem to be active. However, this one does: http://mercurialnet.codeplex.com/

I haven't tested it yet, but it seems to be fairly complete.